# How to display UI dynamically based on date selected?

Tags: javascript

This is how the app looks app [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22uWY.png), pretty simple and what I am trying to do here is display things dynamically and automatically save the data not only for selected movies(I can already do that) but also for dates, which means that every day has several movies, let's say the same ones to make it easier.
Basically in the HTML document, there is an input field where you can choose date [this is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nN2x.png) and when you select a date, its unique seatpicker(right side of the app)should dynamically appear in the UI with corresponding empty/full seats

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-Bfad6CLCknfcloXFOyFnlgtENryhrpZCe29RTifKEixXQZ38WheV+i/6YWSzkz3V" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Movie Seat Booking</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


 <script>
   $(function() {
   $( "#dtb_yr" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>VanillaJS cinema</h1>

    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="movie-selection">

            <div class="movie-container">
                <label>Select date</label>
                
                <input type="text" name="dtb_yr" id="dtb_yr" placeholder="Select Date" />
                
                <label>Select the movie</label>
               
                <select id="movie">
                    <option id="selection" value="0">Press to select...</option>
                    <option id="avengers" value="10">Tron: Legacy</option>
                    <option id="joker" value="12">The Internship</option>
                    <option id="toystory" value="8">The Social Network</option>
                    <option id="lionking" value="9">The Matrix</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="summary-container">
                <div class="items">
                    <p class="text seats-number">Number of seats</p>
                    <p class="text seats-premium-number">Premium seats</p>
                    <p class="text ticket-price">Ticket price</p>
                    <p class="text ticket-premium-price">Ticket premium price</p>
                    <p class="text total-price">Total price</p>
                </div>
                <div class="totals">
                    <p class="number seats-number" id="count">0</p>
                    <p class="number seats-premium-number" id="countpremium">£0</p>
                    <p class="number ticket-price" id="price">£0</p>
                    <p class="number ticket-premium-price" id="premiumprice">£0</p>
                    <p class="number total-price" id="total">£0</p>
                </div>
                
            </div>

            <div class="commands-container">
                <button id="resetselection"><span style="color: tomato;"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></span>
                     Reset</button>
                <button id="confirmselection"><span style="color:limegreen;"><i class="fa fa-pound-sign"></i></span> Pay</button>
            </div>
    
        </div>
        
        <div class="seat-selection">
            <div class="cinema-container">
            
                <div class="screen" id="screen"></div>
        
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                </div>

                <!-- Premium seats central -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                </div>

                <!-- Normal seats -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="showcase">
                <ul class="row-showcase">
                    <li>
                        <div class="seat"></div>
                        <small>Free</small>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                        <small>Premium seat</small>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="row-showcase">
                    <li>
                        <div class="seat selected"></div>
                        <small>Selected</small>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="seat occupied"></div>
                        <small>Occupied</small>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
const cinemacontainer = document.querySelector('.cinema-container');
const seats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat:not(.occupied)');
const count = document.getElementById('count');
const total = document.getElementById('total');
const movieSelect = document.getElementById('movie');

let movieList = [];

getMovieList();
checkStorage();


// #########################################################################
// FUNCTIONS
// #########################################################################

// CHECK STORAGE
function checkStorage() {

    const movieIndex = +localStorage.getItem('selectedMovieIndex');

    if (!(movieIndex === 0)) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('selectedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]) === null) {
            resetSeatGrid();
            localStorage.setItem('selectedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1], '');
            localStorage.setItem('selectedPremiumSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1], '');
            localStorage.setItem('occupiedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1], '');
        }
        else {
            resetSeatGrid();
            populateUI();
            updateSelectedCountAndTotal();
        }
    }
    else if (movieIndex === 0) {
        resetSeatGrid();
        document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = '';
    }
    
}

// ----------------------
// GET MOVIE LIST
function getMovieList() {
    for(i=0;i<movieSelect.options.length;i++) {
        movieList.push([movieSelect.options[i].text, movieSelect.options[i].id]);
    }
}

// ----------------------
// SET MOVIE DATA
// Save selected movie index and price
function setMovieData(movieIndex, moviePrice) {
    localStorage.setItem('selectedMovieIndex', movieIndex);
    localStorage.setItem('selectedMoviePrice', moviePrice);
}

// ----------------------
// POPULATE UI
// Get data from localStorage and populate the UI
function populateUI() {

    if (localStorage.length > 0) {

        const movieIndex = localStorage.getItem('selectedMovieIndex');

        if (movieIndex !== null) {
            movieSelect.selectedIndex = movieIndex;
        }

        if (!(localStorage.getItem('selectedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]) === null) || localStorage.getItem('selectedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]).length > 0) {

            const selectedSeats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]));

            if (selectedSeats !== null && selectedSeats.length > 0) {
                seats.forEach((seat, index) => {
                    if(selectedSeats.indexOf(index) > -1) {
                        seat.classList.add('selected');
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        if (!(localStorage.getItem('selectedPremiumSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]) === null) || localStorage.getItem('selectedPremiumSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]).length > 0) {
            
            const selectedPremiumSeats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedPremiumSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]));

            if (selectedPremiumSeats !== null && selectedPremiumSeats.length > 0) {
                seats.forEach((seat, index) => {
                    if(selectedPremiumSeats.indexOf(index) > -1) {
                        seat.classList.add('selected-premium');
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        if (!(localStorage.getItem('occupiedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]) === null) || localStorage.getItem('occupiedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]).length > 0) {
            
            const occupiedSeats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('occupiedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]));
            
            if (occupiedSeats !== null && occupiedSeats.length > 0) {
                seats.forEach((seat, index) => {
                    if(occupiedSeats.indexOf(index) > -1) {
                        seat.classList.add('occupied');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
};

// ----------------------
// UPDATE SELECTED COUNT AND TOTAL
// Update total and count
function updateSelectedCountAndTotal() {

    if (localStorage.length > 0) {

        const selectedSeats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat.selected');
        const selectedSeatsPremium = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat.selected-premium');
        const occupiedSeats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat.occupied');

        // Copy selected seats into an array
        // Map through that array
        // Return a new array of indexes
        const seatsIndex = [...selectedSeats].map((seat) => [...seats].indexOf(seat));
        const seatsPremiumIndex = [...selectedSeatsPremium].map((seat) => [...seats].indexOf(seat));
        const occupiedIndex = [...occupiedSeats].map((seat) => [...seats].indexOf(seat));

        const movieIndex = localStorage.getItem('selectedMovieIndex');

        localStorage.setItem('selectedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1], JSON.stringify(seatsIndex));
        localStorage.setItem('selectedPremiumSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1], JSON.stringify(seatsPremiumIndex));
        localStorage.setItem('occupiedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1], JSON.stringify(occupiedIndex));

        const selectedSeatsCount = selectedSeats.length;
        const selectedPremiumSeatsCount = selectedSeatsPremium.length;

        count.innerText = selectedSeatsCount;
        countpremium.innerText = selectedPremiumSeatsCount;

        const moviePrice = +localStorage.getItem('selectedMoviePrice');
        price.innerText = "£" + moviePrice.toFixed(2);
        premiumprice.innerText = "£" + (moviePrice * 1.25).toFixed(2);

        total.innerText = "£" + (+(selectedSeatsCount * moviePrice + moviePrice * 1.25 * selectedPremiumSeatsCount)).toFixed(2);

        if (!(movieIndex == 0)) {
            document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = movieList[movieIndex][0];
        }

    }

};


// #########################################################################
// EVENT LISTENER
// #########################################################################

// ----------------------
// SELECT A MOVIE
// Movie select event
movieSelect.addEventListener('change', (e) => {

    setMovieData(e.target.selectedIndex, e.target.value);
    checkStorage();
    
    ticketPrice = +e.target.value;

    updateSelectedCountAndTotal();
});

// ----------------------
// SELECT A SEAT
// Seat click event
cinemacontainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    if(e.target.classList.contains('seat') && !e.target.classList.contains('occupied') && !e.target.classList.contains('premium-seat') && !(movieSelect.options[movieSelect.selectedIndex].id === 'selection')) {
        // with toggle it is possible to apply and remove the class quickly
        e.target.classList.toggle('selected');
        updateSelectedCountAndTotal();
    }

    if(e.target.classList.contains('premium-seat') && !e.target.classList.contains('occupied') && !(movieSelect.options[movieSelect.selectedIndex].id === 'selection')) {
        e.target.classList.toggle('selected-premium');
        updateSelectedCountAndTotal();
    }

});

// ----------------------
// RESET SELECTION
// Cancel selected seats
document.getElementById('resetselection').addEventListener('click', function() {
    resetSelection();
    updateSelectedCountAndTotal();
});

// ----------------------
// CONFIRM SELECTION
// Confirms selected seats and block them
document.getElementById('confirmselection').addEventListener('click', function() {
    confirmSelection();
    updateSelectedCountAndTotal();
});


// #########################################################################
// SELECTION FUNCTIONS
// #########################################################################

function resetSelection() {
    seats.forEach(seat => {
        if (seat.classList.contains('selected')) {
            seat.classList.remove('selected');
        }
        if (seat.classList.contains('selected-premium')) {
            seat.classList.remove('selected-premium');
        }
    });
};

function resetSeatGrid() {
    resetSelection();
    seats.forEach(seat => {
        if (seat.classList.contains('occupied')) {
            seat.classList.remove('occupied');
        }
    });
};

function confirmSelection() {
    seats.forEach(seat => {
        if (seat.classList.contains('selected')) {
            seat.classList.add('occupied');
            seat.classList.remove('selected');
        }
        if (seat.classList.contains('selected-premium')) {
            seat.classList.add('occupied');
            seat.classList.remove('selected-premium');
        }
    });
};
```